# Flask + Jinja2: how to measure performances

Tags: python, performance, flask, jinja2

I need to compare the performances of a Flask application that uses `jinja2.Template.render` against `jinja2.Template.stream` to be sure that there is no loss of performances using the streaming of templates.

My (very simple) idea was to print the timestamp before and after the rendering of the template, but since the webpage is returned by a function, I'm not quite sure how to implement this...

My function is:

```
def index():
    """main function"""
    env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(basedir+'templates'))
    #I modify the global variables
    env.globals['foo'] = 'bar'
    env.globals['build_response']=build_response
    get_url = request.args.get('to_print', None)
    message = "the input was \"%s\"" % (get_url,)
    template = env.get_template('body.html')
    return Response(template.stream(message=message))
    #return template.render(message=message)
```

And what I need to measure is the time spent by

```
return template.render(message=message)
```

vs

```
return Response(template.stream(message=message))
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the system clock before and after the call.

It's easier to do this if you don't immediately return the response from template.render or template.stream.

IE:

```
from time import time

def index():
    # THE REST OF YOUR CODE GOES HERE
    start = time.time()
    resp = template.render(message=message)
    end = time.time()
    processing_time = end - start
    # LOG PROCESSING TIME SOMEPLACE
    return resp
```

Comment: It doesn't work... I mean, it's a good solution for "render", but for stream it's not ok, since `Response(template.stream(message=message))` doesn't actually create the entire response containing the entire page but a streaming handler that can take time to process the entire page...

Comment: Profile the second one in chrome or safari or using something like Charles. In fact do them both there. They'll show you how long the request took soup to nuts. If the only variable is the method in which you're returning the data the difference should be quantifiable as what you're looking for

Comment: Ok... I think you you confirmed that it's not possible to do directly in python but I have to measure it from outside... Right now I'm using Apache Benchmark.

Comment: Yeah, if you can't wrap the stream output in something.  You might want to try looking into this: http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html

Comment: couldn't you measure the response time in with `@app.before_request`and `@app.teardown_request`? This would measure your response time for all pages, but you could filter this out in the logs. Or, just use your web servers access logs to determine how long it took to respond for a given URL.

Comment: @mattb: yes you could totally do this in an `@app.before_request` and `@app.teardown_request`, but I think you'll need to store it in the `g` object.  like `g.start_time = time.time()` in the before function and then calculate the total request processing time in teardown and write it to a log.

Comment: @tkone: if you edit your answer to add the profiling with an external tool, I'll accept it. :-)

Comment: I needed to change `from time import time` to `import time` for `time.time()` to work....FYI

Comment: The import should just be "import time"